# php if statement with either OR is equal to

Tags: php, session, if-statement

I am trying to write an if stement

```
if(($result["from_id"] OR $result["to_id"]) == $_SESSION['user_id']) {
    //DO SOMETHING
}
else {
    // redirect
}
```

Is this the correct way to find out if either of the 2 columns fetched from a certain row has the same value of the current registered session.

Is this also possible?

```
if($result["from_id"] || $result["to_id"] == $_SESSION['user_id']) {
    //DO SOMETHING
}
else {
    // redirect
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to compare both 'from_id' and 'to_id' to 'user_id'?

Comment: I am trying to compare either one of them to see if the id matches up with session id, if either one does, then echo something, if neither one does, then echo something else. @ethrbunny

Answer (score 0):

No, in php you would have to do something like:

```
if ( in_array( $_SESSION['user_id'], array($result["from_id"], $result["to_id"]) ) )
```

or write separated comparisons for every condition (2 in this case, the `in_array` method scales a bit better).

If the results come from mysql, you can use [`IN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) there directly as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your comparison evaluates to something like this assuming those values are set...

```
if( (true || true) == $_SESSION['user_id']){ ... }
```

You need to compare specifically...

```
if( $result["from_id"] == $_SESSION['user_id']|| $result["to_id"] == $_SESSION['user_id']){ ... }
```

So you can see why the first set is not going to do what you are expecting.

But as jeroen said, you may want to run this directly in the query.

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `from_id` = '$_SESSION['user_id']' OR `to_id` = '$_SESSION['user_id']'
```

except obviously escape this properly according to whatever database interface you're using.

Comment: I am pretty much just trying to see if the user logged in has the same id of either the sender or receiver of a private message. if he is, then show the page, if he isnt, then show a no permission error. @KaiQing

Comment: both of these answer are doing exactly that. Just they are correcting the syntax you provided. Did you try them and see if they work?

Comment: I tried that code you sent me **if( $result["from_id"] == $_SESSION['user_id']|| $result["to_id"] == $_SESSION['user_id']){ ... }** but it redirects even if my session value is equal to either from or to.

Comment: Then you should update your question with the exact var_dump of `$_SESSION['user_id']`, `$result['from_id']` and `$result['to_id']` because the syntax in this answer is correct. Also consider incorrect or foreign encoding could technically make what appears to be two identical strings not identical at all.